# Merging df inside a loop with overlapping names and a few matching ids to group on each loop

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a for loop in which I filter a df and try to merge it to a final output dataframe. The `df` on which I am merging looks like this:

```
# df_1
id_1      product_id_left
1         111
2         222
3         333
```

While the `df_2` that changes each loop looks like this:

```
# first loop
id_2    product_id_right         qty         value      
1       abc1                     50          100
1       abc2                     80          600
1       abc3                     80          600
```

```
# second loop
id_2    product_id_right          qty         value   
2       abc1                      60          59        
2       abc3                      70          26
```

```
# third loop and so on
id_2    product_id_right          qty         value   
3       abc1                      60          59
3       abc2                      790         654
3       abc3                      704         154
```

I am trying to merge them in such a way:

```
id_2    product_id_left         product_id_right        qty         value    
1       111                     abc1                    50          100
                                abc2                    80          600
                                abc3                    80          600
2       222                     abc1                    60          59
                                abc3                    70          26
3       333                     abc1                    60          59
                                abc2                    790         654
                                abc3                    704         154
```

Where I merge on `id` and for each value in `df_2` I add a row.
I tried:

```
for dataframe in dataframes:
    df_1 = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on = 'id_1', right_on = 'id_2', how = 'left') # I tried outer, right & inner
```

But I get this kind of matrix structure where most of the fields are blank as during the first loop merge only `id=1` is present so it fills `product_id_2, qty & value` for the first matching `id_1 == id_2` and for the rest just `nans` and has `4*len(dataframes)` columns instead of the desired 4. And overall the structure looks like `np.eye(n)`:

```
np.eye(5)

[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]
```

Where 1 represents the added 3 columns for a matching `id_1 == id_2`.

How could I merge these dataframes to have 4 columns instead of this sparse `df_1` mostly filled with  `nans` and not having overlaping column names as each loop `df_2` has the same column names?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `concat` then `merge`

```
out = pd.concat(dataframes).merge(df_1,left_on='id_2',right_on='id_1').set_index(['id_2','product_id_left'])
```

Comment: In reality I do not have `dataframes`, I generate each `df` during each loop.

Comment: Create the dfs in loop , then concat then after you store them in a list of dfs @JonasPalačionis